# Error in timestamp function

Tags: php

I try to get the count of days between two dates like:

```
$day = ( strtotime('25-09-2013') - strtotime('01-01-2009') ) / ( 24*60*60 );
```

results returns is: "1727.9583333333", How come ?!

Comment: What's wrong? The result is correct

Comment: What's the expected result, then?

Comment: are you going to choose an answer for this question? ^^

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime). It handles this a lot neater:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("01-01-2009");
$date2 = new DateTime("25-09-2013");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "difference = " . $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: The result is the same, the code posted by the OP returns the same value (the only difference is that's not rounded).

Comment: Yes but he won't need to worry about getting the working out correct and rounding

Comment: i feel like my answer has been corrupted

Comment: Thanks sir, Results are right.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason you are getting an uneven result is a daylight savings-related issue. I believe between those two days there is an uneven amount of whole days. There is nothing wrong with your PHP code.

Comment: So is there a solution for this problem ?

Comment: The answer you are getting, best I can tell, is a correct one. So I think the choice is a rounding one; round up, or round down. I suppose a solution whereby something was done to count the days between instead of the seconds between could yield an answer with less rounding. But that solution is long-winded and not worth the time it would take to implement.

Answer (score 1):

## Why?

> results returns is: "1727.9583333333", How come ?!

#### You get that kind of result because you are using timezone that uses [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)<sup>Daylight saving time</sup>.

[image]

<sup>DST is used [blue] | DST is no longer used [orange] | DST has never been used [red]</sup>

## "Solution"?

If you use timezone which isn't using DST, your result will not be float:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Shanghai'); # not in DST
var_dump( (strtotime('25-09-2013') - strtotime('01-01-2009')) / (24*60*60) ); # int(1728)

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); # in DST
var_dump( (strtotime('25-09-2013') - strtotime('01-01-2009')) / (24*60*60) ); # float(1727.9583333333)
```

Above example was for setting timezone globally, but you calculate days with setting time to UTC locally:

```
var_dump( (strtotime('25-09-2013 UTC') - strtotime('01-01-2009 UTC')) / (24*60*60) ); # int(1728)
```

I always suggest to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) instead of *mktime()*, *strtotime()* and similar functions. [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) handles leap years and DST correctly.

```
$f = new DateTime('01-01-2009');
$t = new DateTime('25-09-2013');
var_dump( $f->diff($t)->days ); # int(1728)

# Or one-liner (PHP >= 5.4) :
echo (new DateTime('01-01-2009'))->diff(new DateTime('25-09-2013'))->days; # 1728
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set timezone before using strtotime function

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$day = ( strtotime('25-09-2013') - strtotime('01-01-2009') ) / ( 24*60*60 );
```

if you need to preserve timezone for further processing then you can use get and set commands before and after above code respectively

```
$my_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
```

and later

```
date_default_timezone_set($my_tz);
```